Explain how to find this formula from the recursion in this paper
I am trying to understand how to find this formula, which seems straight forward, but I am missing something.
In page 20 of this paper (or thesis):
https://egrove.olemiss.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2262&context=hon_thesis
The characteristic equation $r^2- (1+x+y)r+ xy= 0$ has roots which are not polynomials themselves, yet they are used to find $T_{F_n}= A r_1^n+ B r_2^n$ where $A,B$ are polynomials of the two variables $x, y$ , then the initial conditions are used to solve for $A$ and $B$,
$T_{F_1}= x+y$ and $T_{F_2}= x^2+ x+ y$ , but how is this working? I tried expanding and calculating but it is not clear.
How do they find $A$ and $B$ from those conditions?
And what is $T_{F_n}$ when $n$ is odd, how will the square root vanish ?
I am referring to their result in page 21 where they keep the roots raised to a power $n$, although the Tutte polynomial must be a polynomial.

In this paper, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257977298_Tutte_polynomials_of_wheels_via_generating_functions/link/00463526ebd6581ee0000000/download?_tp=eyJjb250ZXh0Ijp7ImZpcnN0UGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uIiwicGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uIn19, they mention a computer program! How does a computer program do that?

Note that $A$ and $B$ are not actually polynomials in $x,y$ since they contain references to $r$ which is a non-polynomial algebraic expression in $x,y$.

"how will the square root vanish?" It is typical for the square roots to vanish by cancellation between the two summed terms.  That's true regardless of whether $n$ is odd or even: compare with a simple expression like $(1+\sqrt{2})^n + (1-\sqrt{2})^n$.

It seems there is just a small mistake in Figure 14 of Amanda Hall's thesis regarding the initial condition $T(F_1)$. Since the fan graph $F_n$ is defined as the graph join of the path graph $P_n$ consisting of $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges with the complete graph $K_1$ consisting of a single vertex we have the initial conditions
\begin{align*}
T(F_1)&=x\\
T(F_2)&=x^2+x+y\tag{1}
\end{align*}
With the reduction operations deletion and contraction we can show (1) with a symbolic notation where edges for reduction are marked in bold.
                                             
                                               
With (1) we can derive $A$ and $B$ of the closed formula
\begin{align*}
T(F_n;x,y)=A\left(\frac{w+\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^n
+B\left(\frac{w-\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^n\qquad\qquad n\geq 1\tag{2}
\end{align*}
where we use the short-hand notation $w:=1+x+y$ and $\sqrt{\Box} :=\sqrt{w^2-4xy}$ in accordance with formula (11) of A. Hall's thesis:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{T(F_n;x,y)}
&\color{blue}{=\frac{x^2-xy+y+1-(1-x)\sqrt{\Box}}{2x\sqrt{\Box}}
\left(\frac{w+\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^n}\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{-\frac{x^2-xy+y+1+(1-x)\sqrt{\Box}}{2x\sqrt{\Box}}
\left(\frac{w-\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^n\qquad n\geq 1}\tag{3}\\
\end{align*}
We start with the calculation of $B$.
Calculation of $B$:
We use the initial conditions (1) in (2) and consider
\begin{align*}
x&=\frac{1}{2}A\left(w+\sqrt{\Box}\right)+\frac{1}{2}B\left(w-\sqrt{\Box}\right)\tag{4.1}\\
x^2+x+y&=\frac{1}{4}A\left(w+\sqrt{\Box}\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}B\left(w-\sqrt{\Box}\right)^2\tag{4.2}\\
\end{align*}
We multiply equation (4.1) by $\frac{1}{2}\left(w+\sqrt{\Box}\right)$ and get
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}x\left(w+\sqrt{\Box}\right)
=\frac{1}{4}A\left(w+\sqrt{\Box}\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}B\left(w^2-{\sqrt{\Box}}^2\right)^2
\end{align*}
Subtracting it from (4.2) we get
\begin{align*}
x^2&+x+y-\frac{1}{2}x\left(w+\sqrt{\Box}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}B\left(\left(w-\sqrt{\Box}\right)^2-\left(w^2-\sqrt{\Box}^2\right)\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}B\sqrt{\Box}\left(w-\sqrt{\Box}\right)
\end{align*}
We put $B$ on one side and derive noting that $\left(w^2-\sqrt{\Box}^2\right)=4xy$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{B}
&\color{blue}{=\frac{x\left(w+\sqrt{\Box}\right)-2\left(x^2+x+y\right)}
{\sqrt{\Box}\left(w-\sqrt{\Box}\right)}}\\
&=\frac{x\left(w+\sqrt{\Box}\right)^2-2\left(x^2+x+y\right)\left(w+\sqrt{\Box}\right)}
{4xy\sqrt{\Box}}\\
&=\big(xw^2+2xw\sqrt{\Box}+x\sqrt{\Box}^2-2x^2w-2xw-2yw\\
&\qquad-2x^2\sqrt{\Box}-2x\sqrt{\Box}-2y\sqrt{\Box}\big)\frac{1}{4xy\sqrt{\Box}}\\
&=\cdots\\
&=\big(xw^2-2x^2y-w\left(x^2+x+y\right)\\
&\qquad+\left(xw-x^2-x-y\right)\sqrt{\Box}\big)\frac{1}{2xy\sqrt{\Box}}\\
&=\cdots\\
&=\frac{-y\left(x^2-xy+y+1\right)-(1-x)y\sqrt{\Box}}{2xy\sqrt{\Box}}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=-\frac{x^2-xy+y+1+(1-x)\sqrt{\Box}}{2x\sqrt{\Box}}}
\end{align*}
in accordance with (3). The calculation of $A$ can be carried out in a similar way.

[Supplement 2024-12-21]
Another thread to derive $A$ and $B$ in (2) is based upon a generating function for $T(F_n)$. Such a function is stated in Tutte polynomials of wheels via generating functions by C. Brennan, T. Mansour and E. Mphako-Banda in a proof of Lemma 2 as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{F(z)}&=\frac{\frac{xz}{1-xz}+\frac{yz^2}{(1-xz)(1-yz)}}
{1-\frac{z}{(1-xz)(1-yz)}}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{xz+(1-z)yz^2}{1-(x+y+1)z+xyz^2}}\tag{5}\\
&=xz+\left(x^2+x+y\right)z^2\\
&\qquad+\left(x^3+2x^2+2xy+x+y^2+y\right)z^3\\
&\qquad+\big(x^4+3x^3+3x^2(y+1)+x\left(2y^2+4y+1\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad+y(y+1)^2z^4\big)
+\mathcal{O}\left(z^5\right)\tag{6}
\end{align*}
The expansion of the series was done with some help of Wolfram Alpha. Note, the coefficients $[z]F(z)=x$ and $[z^2]F(z)=x^2+x+y$ are in accordance with the initial conditions in (1). The series expansion in (6) is also in accordance with the recurrence formula
\begin{align*}
T(F_n;x,y)&=(x+y+1)T(F_{n-1};x,y)-xyT(F_{n-2};x,y)\qquad \qquad n\geq 2\\
\end{align*}
which is formula (9) in Amanda Hall's thesis. The coefficient $[z^4]F(z)$ given in (6) coincides with formula (12) in Amanda Hall's thesis.
Closed formula for $T(F_n)$
We derive a closed formula (2) from the generating function (5) by partial fraction decomposition followed by a geometric series expansion. We use again the short-hand notation $w:=1+ x+y$ and $\sqrt{\Box}:=\sqrt{w^2-4xy}$ and derive
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{F(z)
=\frac{xz+(1-x)yz^2}{\sqrt{\Box}}
\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac{w+\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^{q+1}
-\left(\frac{w-\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^{q+1}\right)}z^q\tag{7}
\end{align*}
Denoting with $[z^n]$ the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series we obtain from (7)
\begin{align*}
T&(F_n;x,y)=[z^n]F(z)\\
&=\frac{x}{\sqrt{\Box}}
\left(\left(\frac{w+\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{w-\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^n\right)\\
&\qquad+\frac{(1-x)y}{\sqrt{\Box}}
\left(\left(\frac{w+\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^{n-1}-\left(\frac{w-\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^{n-1}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\Box}}+\frac{2(1-x)y}{\sqrt{\Box}\left(w+\sqrt{\Box}\right)}\right)
\left(\frac{w+\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^n\\
&\qquad-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\Box}}+\frac{2(1-x)y}{\left(w-\sqrt{\Box}\right)}\right)
\left(\frac{w-\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^n\tag{8}\\
\end{align*}
The left part of the first summand in (8) can be written as
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{\Box}}&+\frac{2(1-x)y}{\sqrt{\Box}\left(w+\sqrt{\Box}\right)}\\
&=\frac{x}{\sqrt{\Box}}+\frac{(1-x)\left(w-\sqrt{\Box}\right)}{2x\sqrt{\Box}}\\
&=\frac{2x^2+(1-x)(1+x+y)-(1-x)\sqrt{\Box}}{2x\sqrt{\Box}}\\
&=\frac{x^2-xy+y+1-(1-x)\sqrt{\Box}}{2x\sqrt{\Box}}\tag{9}
\end{align*}
and similarly the left part of the second summand is
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{\Box}}&+\frac{2(1-x)y}{\sqrt{\Box}\left(w-\sqrt{\Box}\right)}\\
&=\frac{x}{\sqrt{\Box}}+\frac{(1-x)\left(w+\sqrt{\Box}\right)}{2x\sqrt{\Box}}\\
&=\frac{2x^2+(1-x)(1+x+y)+(1-x)\sqrt{\Box}}{2x\sqrt{\Box}}\\
&=\frac{x^2-xy+y+1+(1-x)\sqrt{\Box}}{2x\sqrt{\Box}}\tag{10}
\end{align*}
Finally, if we insert (9) and (10) into (8), we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{T}&{\color{blue}{(F_n;x,y)}}=[z^n]F(z)\\
&\color{blue}{=\frac{x^2-xy+y+1-(1-x)\sqrt{\Box}}{2x\sqrt{\Box}}
\left(\frac{w+\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^n}\\
&\color{blue}{\qquad-\frac{x^2-xy+y+1+(1-x)\sqrt{\Box}}{2x\sqrt{\Box}}
\left(\frac{w-\sqrt{\Box}}{2}\right)^n}
\end{align*}
in accordance with (3).
Note: The Handbook of the Tutte Polynomial and Related Topics presents some formulas for fan graphs in section 7.2. It uses the two papers mentioned in this answer as essential references on fan graphs.
